# Illustrator edit link filepath via javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, adobe, adobe-illustrator

Edit, original copy marked below:
I've managed to create a semi-functioning script. I realized, to much frustration, that the syntax errors were the '' marks of text edit. It semi-works in that it will relink some files and usually ends in an error, "placedArt does not exist" after a few loops through. I feel like the XML finds more "stRef:filePath"s than exist in the file. Example: file with two images finds a file path for each twice. Any tips?

```
var counter = 0;
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var x = new XML(doc.XMPString);
var m = x.xpath('//stRef:filePath');
if (m !== '') {
  for (var i=0, len=m.length(); i < len ; i++) {
  var link_path = m[i];
  if ( File(link_path).exists === false ) {
    link_path = link_path.split('/Projects').join('/Volumes/Projects')
    link_path = link_path.split('O:').join('/Volumes/Projects');
    link_path = link_path.split('P:').join('/Volumes/Projects');
    link_path = link_path.split('\\SERVER').join('Volumes');
    link_path = link_path.split("\\").join("/");

    if ( File(link_path).exists === true ){
      placedArt = app.activeDocument.placedItems[i];
      placedArt.relink(new File (link_path));}
    alert(File(link_path).fsName);
    counter++;
  }

};}

if ( counter > 0 ) {
  alert("Attempted to relink " + counter + " links");}
else {
  alert("No links replaced");}
```

*orginal post*
Okay, I'm very inexperienced XML, but I'm trying to edit parts of a link filepath in Adobe Illustrator using a script. Below is what I have so far:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var x = new XML(doc.XMPString);
var m = x.xpath('//stRef:filePath');
if (m !== '') {
   for (var i=0, len=m.length(); i < len ; i++) {
   var link_path = m[i];
   if ( File(link_path).exists === false ) {
      var link_path2 = String(link_path)
      link_path2 = link_path2.replace(‘%5C’, ‘/‘)
      alert(File(link_path2));
  }
};
}
```

This returns an error:8 syntax error. on the line link_path2 = link_path2.replace(‘%5C’, ‘/‘). So does any attempt to redefine link_path2, such as

```
link_path2 = 'cow';
```

I currently am  changing, the link_path to link_path2 to convert it into a string, assuming that the fact that the var link_path returns typeof XML is an issue for redefining, or editing the value.

The end goal is to edit the filepath from a windows server path to a macOS filepath, to script fix broken links. I've searched for hours on this, and keep hitting dead ends.

Answer (score 0):

I don't if XML/XMP data is the best way to do this. We had a similar issue with linked files at our firm in swapping linked images from one server to another. This opens each AI file, looks for placed items and relinks the images to the new path. I have only used this on a PC, so I am not sure if this will work without the Mac path being available, but figured you could try.

Are you always using the same two file paths, or would you like to select them uniquely each time? If you have a two set server paths that you just want to swap, you can use something like this (I have a similar one where you pick the initial location and the destination for the files):

```
// Select the source folder.
var destFolder, sourceFolder, files, fileType, doc, targetFile, pngExportOpts;

if (app.documents.length == 0 ){
sourceFolder = Folder.selectDialog( 'Select the folder with Illustrator files you want to relink', '~' );

    // If a valid folder is selected
    if ( sourceFolder != null ){
        files = new Array();
        // Get all files matching the filetype
        files = sourceFolder.getFiles("*.ai");

        if ( files.length > 0 ) {

            for ( i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ){
                doc = app.open(files[i]); // returns the document object
                changeExt();
                if (app.documents.length != 0){
                    doc.save();
                    doc.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else{
    changeExt();
    }



function changeExt(){

var i;
var doc = app.activeDocument;

if (doc.placedItems.length != 0){
     for (i=0;i<doc.placedItems.length;i++) {
        //gets the full path of the image
    var imageName = doc.placedItems[i].file.fsName;
    var imageURL = doc.placedItems[i].uRL;
    var imagePath;

    var newPath;

    var i, in_file, out_file;
        //if the scan is placed for the first time it uses the drive letter
        //this swaps the drive letters to the server names so they can be replaced properly
        if (imageName.match(/O:/)){
        imagePath = imageName.replace("O:", "\\\\Serv01\\Projects1")
        imageName = imagePath;

        }
        else (imageName.match(/P:/)){
        imagePath = imageName.replace("P:", "\\\\Serv02\\Projects2")
        imageName = imagePath;
        }

    if (imageName.match(/Serv02/)){
        imagePath = imageName.replace("Serv02", "Serv01")
        activePath = imagePath.replace("Projects2", "Projects1");
        newPath = File(activePath);
            if (newPath.exists){//copies scan over if it doesn't exist.
               doc.placedItems[i].file = newPath;
            }
            else{
                in_file = doc.placedItems[i].file;
                out_file = File(activePath);
                in_file.copy(out_file);
                doc.placedItems[i].file = out_file;
            }
        }
    else{
         imagePath = imageName.replace("Serv01", "Serv02")
        activePath = imagePath.replace("Projects1", "Projects2");
        newPath = File(activePath);
       if (newPath.exists){//copies scan over if it doesn't exist.
               doc.placedItems[i].file = newPath;
            }
            else{
                in_file = doc.placedItems[i].file;
                out_file = File(activePath);
                in_file.copy(out_file);
                doc.placedItems[i].file = out_file;
            }
        }

}
}
else{
    doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'll have to examine this more closely and try to mix this with mine. I actually got a semi-functioning version using a mix of placedItems and XML. I was running into the issue of placedItems of broken links not having a .fsname, .url, or .file.name to edit (an alert shows [placed item]/ or unknown). Maybe this is a change of platform issue, but I was relinking an open file, I'll have to try relinking an unopened file. Unfortunately the servers here are a cluster F and it rarely involves the same two paths.

Either way, you've given me a new route of testing/exploring so, merçi beaucoup.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the case and the starting point and ending point are different, we used a script like this for transferring files with links from one location to another, and allows you to pick the starting location and the destination. Again, can't promise it will work for a Mac, but maybe some of this can help you. In our setup we store graphics in one folder and scans in another, so you may need to adjust the file paths if you keep it all in one folder. So we have a root folder and within that folder a "Graphics" folder and a "Scans" folder.

This also has a try/catch for files missing scans and will spit them out in an error list at the end so you know which files have missing images.

Hope some of this helps!

```
    // Select the source folder.
sourceFolder = Folder.selectDialog( 'Select the GRAPHICS folder with Illustrator files you want to move', '~' );

var export_folderSelect = Folder.selectDialog("Select the root folder (NOT GRAPHICS) to move the Illustrator files to");
var export_folder = export_folderSelect + "/Graphics";

var errorList = [];

var destFolder, sourceFolder, files, fileType, doc, targetFile, pngExportOpts;

var save_options = new IllustratorSaveOptions();
save_options.embedICCProfile = true;
save_options.pdfCompatible = true;

// If a valid folder is selected
if ( sourceFolder != null  && export_folderSelect != null){
files = new Array();

// Get all files matching the pattern
files = sourceFolder.getFiles("*.ai");

if ( files.length > 0 ){
// Get the destination to save the files
app.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevel.DONTDISPLAYALERTS;
    for ( i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ){
        //try to open the file and move it over, otherwise note it in the error list.
        var docOpened = true;
        try{
            doc = app.open(files[i]); // returns the document object
            }
        catch(e){
            errorList.push(files[i].name + " !!!CORRUPT - NOT COPIED!!!");
            docOpened = false;
            }
        try{
             moveFile();
             }
         catch(e){
              if (docOpened == true){
                doc.close();
              }
        }
    }
}

if (errorList.length > 0){
    alert("COPY THIS LIST TO WORD: " + errorList);
    }
else{
    alert("Woo hoo! No errors!");
    }
app.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevel.DISPLAYALERTS;
}

function moveFile(){

const FILE_SUFFIX = "";

const ASSET_SUFFIX = "";

var doc = app.activeDocument;

if (!doc.saved) doc.save();

var original_file = doc.fullName;
var extension = "";

var arr = doc.name.split(".");
if (arr.length>1) extension = "." + arr.pop();

var filename = arr.join(".");

var assets_folder = new Folder(export_folderSelect + "/Scans");

if (assets_folder.exists || assets_folder.create()) {

          var f, in_file, out_file;

          for (f=0;f<doc.placedItems.length;f++) {

                   try{
                        in_file = doc.placedItems[f].file;

                        out_file = File(assets_folder+"/"+in_file.name);

                        in_file.copy(out_file);

                        doc.placedItems[f].file = out_file;
                    }
                    catch(e){
                             errorList.push(files[i].name + " SCAN MISSING");
                        }


          }

          for (g=0;g<doc.rasterItems.length;g++) {

                    if (doc.rasterItems[g].embedded == false) {

                           try{
                           in_file = doc.rasterItems[g].file;

                            out_file = File(assets_folder+"/"+in_file.name);

                            in_file.copy(out_file);

                            doc.rasterItems[g].file = out_file;
                             }
                        catch(e){
                             errorList.push(files[i].name + " SCAN MISSING");
                            }
                        }

          }
          // save as new file

          packaged_file = File(export_folder + "/" + filename + FILE_SUFFIX + extension);


          doc.saveAs(packaged_file, save_options);

          doc.close();



          // re-open the original file

          //app.open(File(original_file));



} else {
          alert("Unable to create the assets folder.");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly but it may solve your problem or be helpful to others.

There is a totally different solution.

**Illustrator always looks for missing artwork in a "Links" folder in the same folder as the document.**

If you regularly need to move projects around, just keep the artwork in a "Links" folder with the AI file and you can open the AI file anywhere without breaking the links.

Answer (score 0):

Why are using XMP Data for this? You can get all placedItems placed in the document and you can check whether links exist or not and if not exists you relink them to the new file. Here is the small script for this

```
var activeDocument = app.activeDocument;
var links = activeDocument.placedItems;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    try {
        var file = links[i].file;
        if (file && file.exists) {
            // Do anything as oer your requirement if link exists.
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // if link missing relink with new_File
        links[i].relink(File(new_File));
    }
}
```

When you relink links for missing links, it will automatically update in  document XMP.